# Value assigned remains null

Tags: android, variables, null

Here is a piece of code which befuddles me: I have a String name reviewChoisi which carries a value (for instance review3). In the method below, I cannot use it to set the MediaPlayer mp:

```
    public void playCheck(){

    zoneAffichage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zone_trado_scrollable);
    maReponse = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextMaReponse);

    Resources res = getResources();

    final int resRaw = res.getIdentifier(reviewChoisi, "raw", getPackageName());

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resRaw);

    final Button monBouton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.check);
    monBouton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                lireXMLSolution(reviewChoisi);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if ( maReponse.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(laSolution) ) {
                mp.start();
                zoneAffichage.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"blue\">right</font>"));

            }
            else{
                zoneAffichage.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">wrong</font>"));
            }

        }
    });
}
```

The crash happens at line

```
        final int resRaw = res.getIdentifier(reviewChoisi, "raw", getPackageName());
```

I tried tests with a variable son in various places, but it didn't change anything.

Help welcome.

Comment: You can directly show set all value ti TextView using '+' like zoneAffichage.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"blue\">right</font>")+"\n son = " + son+"\n reviewChoisi = " + reviewChoisi); instead of append.

Answer (score 1):

son is declared in the function playCheck, once you run that function, the variable is destroyed. Since onClick events will be occurring after the function has run, the son variable will already have been destroyed, and you won't be able to use it. You still have access to the other variables because, they are global variables. The reason the compiler requires son to be final for it to work is because, if it is final it's value won't change, so the program can save it's value and reuse it. However, my guess is that when you set son equal to reviewChoisi, reviewChoisi has not yet been created, so the value that get saved for son is null.

Comment: You are probably close to the explanation. But if i remove final as you suggest, the compilation debugger says in the line "zoneAffichage.append("\n son = " + son); " that son should be made final. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I know what the problem is now. I'll change the answer.

Comment: So far, it doesn't work. What I really want is to pass reviewChoisi as a parameter in "final int resRaw = res.getIdentifier(reviewChoisi, "raw", getPackageName());" . But it crashes. Even if I assign reviewChoisi to son, and pass son. However with "review1" hard coded it works. But of course it's not what I want. And reviewChoisi is well defined before; and indeed I can even display it successfully, although not son !!! That's the state of the riddle so far.

Comment: Well if it crashes, then it should be throwing an exception, so what is it?

Comment: When I write "final int resRaw = res.getIdentifier(reviewChoisi, "raw", getPackageName());", as I really want, the compiler crashes. See my edited question to read what it says.

Comment: I think it's really simple. You've need to declare MediaPlayer at the top of the class. Then it will not need to be final and nor will the other variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91352/discussion-between-andy-and-geokavel).

Answer (score 0):

Finally a solution was to put the use of reviewChoisi *inside* the body of onClick(View v) {...}, with the following code

```
final int resRaw = getResources().getIdentifier(reviewChoisi, "raw", getPackageName());
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ReviewActivity.this, resRaw);
```